# VBA - Excel - Error 13

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA, I am getting this Error 13 - types mismtached but I have no idea why and I found nothing helpful...
any hint ? (Sorry it's in french)

```
Function EIDPA(Coût_actif, Tx_dépréciation, Tx_marginal, Coût_opportunité)
    EIDPA = ((Coût_actif * Tx_dépréciation * Tx_marginal) / (Coût_opportunité + Tx_dépréciation)) * ((1 + (0.5 * Coût_opportunité)) / (1 + Coût_opportunité))
End Function

Sub EIDPA2()
    Coût_actif = InputBox("Entrez le coût de l'actif SVP", "Calculateur", "100000")
    Tx_dépréciation = InputBox("Entrez le taux de dépréciation pour ammortissement SVP", "Calculateur", "0.30")
    Tx_marginal = InputBox("Entrez le taux marginal d'imposition SVP", "Calculateur", "0.50")
    Coût_opportunité = InputBox("Entrez le coût d'opportunité applicable SVP", "Calculateur", "0.05")
    MsgBox "La valeur actuelle des économies d'impôts est de: " _
    & Module1.EIDPA(Coût_actif, Tx_dépréciation, Tx_marginal, Coût_opportunité) & "$", vbInformation, "Calculateur"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be properly `Dim`ming your variables; otherwise you're attempting to use string variables as numerics:

```
Function EIDPA(Coût_actif As Double, Tx_dépréciation As Double, Tx_marginal As Double, Coût_opportunité As Double) As Double
    EIDPA = ((Coût_actif * Tx_dépréciation * Tx_marginal) / (Coût_opportunité + Tx_dépréciation)) * ((1 + (0.5 * Coût_opportunité)) / (1 + Coût_opportunité))
End Function
Sub EIDPA2()
    Dim Coût_actif  As Double
    Dim Tx_dépréciation As Double
    Dim Tx_marginal  As Double
    Dim Coût_opportunité As Double

    Coût_actif = CDbl(InputBox("Entrez le coût de l'actif SVP", "Calculateur", "100000"))
    Tx_dépréciation = CDbl(InputBox("Entrez le taux de dépréciation pour ammortissement SVP", "Calculateur", "0.30"))
    Tx_marginal = CDbl(InputBox("Entrez le taux marginal d'imposition SVP", "Calculateur", "0.50"))
    Coût_opportunité = CDbl(InputBox("Entrez le coût d'opportunité applicable SVP", "Calculateur", "0.05"))
    MsgBox "La valeur actuelle des économies d'impôts est de: " _
    & Module1.EIDPA(Coût_actif, Tx_dépréciation, Tx_marginal, Coût_opportunité) & "$", vbInformation, "Calculateur"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because InputBox returns strings, and you're trying to multiply strings together here:

`EIDPA = ((Coût_actif * Tx_dépréciation * Tx_marginal) / (Coût_opportunité + Tx_dépréciation)) * ((1 + (0.5 * Coût_opportunité)) / (1 + Coût_opportunité))`.

Try declaring your French variables as integers/floating point to see if that helps.  [More info](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/inputbox.htm)